# VS not storing password in connection string, getting errors when dropping objects into dataclasses

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I have no issues with windows authentication.  However, using sql server authentication and selecting to save my password on the connection properties seems to work fine to pull up the databases and tables of a particular sql server instance, but when I try to drag and drop table objects into the object relational designer I get the following error...

"Failed to retrieve data for this request. Failed to connect to server (local).  Login failed for user 'myusername'".

I've tried changing some advanced settings such as "authentication = sql password" to no avail.  As far as I can tell, it is not storing my password in the connection string and I cannot find any way to manually change this.  It forces me to use the dialog box to make changes to the connection string.  My password is entered but is just ********* so ultimately it seems it really is not remembered (even though I've checked that box) and thus why i'm getting the login errors when dragging and dropping tables.

Does anyone know a workaround or fix....or if I'm missing something obvious.  In the past (VS2013, VS2015) I don't remember having this issue.

Note that the string looks proper in the app.config file but still does not allow me to drag and drop tables from object explorer.

Comment: Are you using the DataSource Configuration wizard to import your database?  When i go through the wizard, it has a screen where you can select an existing saved connection string from your project settings.

Comment: while I am able to connect and create some .xsd objects/files (or whatever they are), it is not clear to me how to get O/R objects from these like from the SQL object explorer.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: This "dataset" appears to be quite different and doesn't even use linq to sql as far as I can tell....so probably not what I want unless you know of something I'm missing.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/dataset-tools-in-visual-studio

"Datasets and related classes are legacy .NET technologies from the early 2000s that enable applications to work with data in memory while the applications are disconnected from the database."